# How to set the camera within a cube?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, glulookat

I have cube which has different color to each side-lock -

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        final GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);




        ///// SET CAMERA  /////  
        setCamera(gl, glu, 100);




        // /////// Cube - start ///////////

        // cube

        // ----- Render the Color Cube -----
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset the current model-view matrix
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0.0f, -7.0f); // translate right and into the
                                                // screen
        gl.glRotatef(angleCube, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // rotate about the x, y and
                                                    // z-axes

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS); // of the color cube

        // Top-face
        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // green
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Bottom-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f); // orange
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Front-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // red
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Back-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // yellow
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Left-face
        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // blue
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Right-face
        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // violet
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        gl.glEnd(); // of the color cube

        // /////// Cube - end //////////



    }

private void setCamera(GL gl, GLU glu, float distance) {
        // Change to projection matrix.
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // Perspective.
        float widthHeightRatio = (float) getWidth() / (float) getHeight();
        glu.gluPerspective(1, widthHeightRatio, 1, 1000);
        glu.gluLookAt(0,0, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        // Change back to model view matrix.
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

At this state  - the figure I get is  -

[image]

Means the camera located in front of the cube  .

Since I trying to set the camera within the cube  , I change the z-axis value in `glu.gluLookAt` to  - `glu.gluLookAt(0,0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);` and know what I get is  -

[image]

And if I change to  - `glu.gluLookAt(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);` I get whole screen black .

So , what I have to change in order to set the camera within the cube - means the excepted figure would be different color in right , left up and down .

Comment: -1, excessive vertical whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

`glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)` doesn't seem valid. Try setting it to 
`glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0)`

EDIT:

1. Remove `glTranslatef`
2. ```
   glu.gluPerspective(100, widthHeightRatio, 0.5, 1000);
   glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, -1.0, 0, 1, 0);
   ```

Comment: It gives yellow in all the screen  , as the 2nd pic I attached .

Comment: yeah, it's all yellow because you're now inside the cube and all you can see is the face located at z=-1